# How to group and count items (read from a file) by time?

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

I'm trying to take an input from a file where a line contains 2 fields: 
(TIME, STATUS)

```
13:23, HELLO
15:34, BYE
16:34, TESTING
13:12, BYE
```

Using Python, what I've done is gotten the input file into the following format in a list:

```
[('13:00', 'HELLO'), ('16:00', 'TESTING'), ('18:00', 'BYE'), ('15:00', 'BYE'), ('18:00', 'HELLO'), ('13:00', 'BYE'), ('13:00', 'HELLO')]
```

So then I can use Counter from collections to count how many times the STATUS appears giving me the below:

```
Counter({('13:00', 'HELLO'): 2, ('16:00', 'TESTING'): 1, ('18:00', 'BYE'): 1, ('15:00', 'BYE'): 1, ('18:00', 'HELLO'): 1, ('13:00', 'BYE'): 1})
```

What I want to do is count how many times the STATUS appears and then group it based on time so that the final output is: (TIME, HELLO COUNT, BYE COUNT, TESTING COUNT)

```
(13:00, 2, 1, 0)
(16:00, 0, 0, 1)
(18:00, 1, 1, 0)
(15:00, 0, 1, 0)
```

However, I can't figure out how to get it into that format.

I tried to use a list comprehension but didn't understand as to how I can pass the counter of each STATUS into the list all at once.

Any advice as to how to go about it?

Comment: Does it need to be using a list of tuples? I would start filling a dict while manipulating the time stamps. But if you need to have a list of tuples it's something different

Comment: It doesn't need to start out as a list of tuples, it just helped in terms of getting to where I got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count your items.

It first groups your `Counter` object into something like `{'13:00': Counter({'HELLO': 2, 'BYE': 1}), '16:00': Counter({'TESTING': 1})`, then just unpacks the result into (TIME, HELLO COUNT, BYE COUNT, TESTING COUNT) tuples.

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

d = Counter({('13:00', 'HELLO'): 2, ('16:00', 'TESTING'): 1, ('18:00', 'BYE'): 1, ('15:00', 'BYE'): 1, ('18:00', 'HELLO'): 1, ('13:00', 'BYE'): 1})

count_keys = ['HELLO', 'BYE', 'TESTING']

# count and group 
counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for (time, count), testing in d.items():
    counts[time][count] += testing

# output and unpack items from count dictionary
print([(k1, *(v1[k2] for k2 in count_keys)) for k1, v1 in counts.items()])
```

Output:

```
[('13:00', 2, 1, 0), ('16:00', 0, 0, 1), ('18:00', 1, 1, 0), ('15:00', 0, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: I went with this answer not only because it works but I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used.

```
items = [('13:00', 'HELLO'), ('16:00', 'TESTING'), ('18:00', 'BYE'), ('15:00', 'BYE'), ('18:00', 'HELLO'), ('13:00', 'BYE'), ('13:00', 'HELLO')]
data = {}
indexs = {"HELLO": 0, "BYE": 1, "TESTING": 2}
for item in items:
     if item[0] not in data:
         data[item[0]] = [0,0,0]
     data[item[0]][indexs[item[1]]] += 1
print([tuple([k]+v) for k, v in data.items()])
```